# Is there any way to pass an FontAwesomeIcon component via props to ReactHTMLTableToExcel component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, font-awesome

ReactHTMLTableToExcel accepts a prop buttonText of type String,

```
<ReactHTMLTableToExcel
                   id="test-table-xls-button"
                   className="download-table-xls-button"
                   table="table-to-xls"
                   filename="tablexls"
                   sheet="tablexls"
                   buttonText="Download as XLS"/>
```

I want to display a fontawesome icon instead of text so modify the code like this.

```
<ReactHTMLTableToExcel
                id="test-table-xls-button"
                className="download-table-xls-button"
                table="table-to-xls"
                filename="tablexls"
                sheet="tablexls"
                buttonText={<IconDownload />} />
```

This actually works fine, I mean I can see the icon button but I get an error on the console : 
 Failed prop type: Invalid prop `buttonText` of type `object` supplied to `ReactHTMLTableToExcel`, expected `string`.

This is the link of the library : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-table-to-excel

So, how can I avoid the errors?

Answer (score 3):

One alternative would be to pass it an empty string (or a space, if it checks against null), then use a CSS::before property to include your fontAwesome icon in the content. This would avoid the PropTypes warning.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the library component expects an string for this property, You are providing an object instead. so the short answer is you shouldn't do this.
But you can indeed create custom version of the library and change the proptype to object, and modify rendering of icon according to the way you need. but passing object to an string prop and looking for a way to suppress the warning is not recommended in general.

Answer (score 0):

I found this https://github.com/zsusac/ReactHTMLTableToExcel/issues/5
https://github.com/zsusac/ReactHTMLTableToExcel/pull/9

After editing the below files, it did not throw error in the console

**1. node_modules/react-html-table-to-excel/src/ReactHTMLTableToExcel.jsx
and adding extra property "object"**

```
buttonText: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.string, 
    PropTypes.object,
  ]),
```

And the second file

**2.node_modules/react-html-table-to-excel/index.js**

```
buttonText: _propTypes2.default.oneOfType([ 
    _propTypes2.default.string, _propTypes2.default.object]),
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question have been asked for a while, but I have directed the same problem and the best solution is to make a button that holds your icon and when we have to on it, turn on this code
()=> document.getElementById("test-table-xls-button").click()

my code

```
<ReactHtmlTableToExcel
                id="test-table-xls-button"
                className="download-table-xls-button"
                table="table-to-xls"
                filename={nameFile}
                sheet="tablexls"
                buttonText={""}
             
                
                />
          
  <button onClick={()=> document.getElementById("test-tablexls- 
  button").click()}><RiFileExcel2Fill size={27} color={"green"}/>  
  </button>
```